# Global hotkeys in Mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono, x11

I'm trying to implement global hotkeys in Mono and X11. Unfortunately the application uses `System.Windows.Forms`, so I can't use the GDK# event filter proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349958/global-hotkey-in-mono-and-gtk).

Using `XGrabKey` works, but I've got a problem with the event loop. When closing the application, the thread handling the X11 event loop still hangs in `XNextEvent`. Is there a way around that? I'd rather not resort to polling with `XPending`. Can I somehow cancel `XNextEvent` or send a dummy event?

I'm calling `XGrabKey` on the root window, so unfortunately I don't get any events like `DestroyNotify` or `UnmapNotify`.

Comment: Why not have a platform specific portion of your program? then you could use GDK/GTK. Anyhoo..

Comment: Well, this is part of the platform specific portion, as obviously using `XGrabKey` won't work on Windows. But migration from SWF to Gtk# is not an option, and pulling in the whole Gtk# just for this seems like overkill.

Comment: I know this is very old post but I'm on the same situation and seems you managed to get it working, do you have any place where this code is available? Or can you post it as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XSendEvent` to send an `XClientMessageEvent`. Create your own atom and set the `Atom` member of the event, so that other apps that might be watching for `XClientMessageEvent` on the root window are not affected.

In your event loop, check for this atom, and exit if you get it.

Comment: I did something similar now. Since I need a window anyway, I'm using the window's `DestroyNotify` event instead of a `ClientMessage`. The proposed solution should work too though.