# Know active window by using x11-api and Mono/C#

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, x11

I'm trying to use X11-api with Mono and C# on Ubuntu.
I have a SIGSEGV when I'm trying to know active window.

Import:

```
[DllImport("libX11")]
public static extern void XGetInputFocus(IntPtr display, IntPtr focus_return, int revert_to_return);

[DllImport("libX11")]
public static extern IntPtr XOpenDisplay(string display_name);
```

And using:

```
IntPtr rootWind = XOpenDisplay(null);           
IntPtr wind;
int ret = 0;

XGetInputFocus(rootWind, wind, ret); //SIGSEGV there
```

I've tried to use pointers, references and some more, but there's one result.
Some other [api-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349958/global-hotkey-in-mono-and-gtk) works normally.
What`s wrong?

Comment: `focus_return` and `revert_to_return` are *out* parameters.

Comment: @n.m. yeah, I tried. «out», [out] and pointers too. Doesn't work... Also, IntPtr is the pointer to a structure.

Comment: Oh, I has used «out» for all parameters (like [there](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XGetInputFocus.html)), thank you, @n.m.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[DllImport("libX11")]
public static extern void XGetInputFocus(IntPtr display, ref IntPtr focus_return, ref int revert_to_return);

IntPtr rootWind = XOpenDisplay(null);           
IntPtr wind;
int ret = 0;
XGetInputFocus(rootWind, ref wind, ref ret);
```